# Why am I getting a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java, jdbc, classnotfoundexception

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

i am   getting this error after executing apache in Eclipse helios and i am using MYSQLyog ultimate

please help...how to remove this error...??

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to solve this issue however, this is generally the easiest.

1. Copy the MySQL driver to your project in eclipse. It is a jar file that comes with the MySQL driver: [MySQL Driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)
2. Right click on the jar and select 'Build Path' -> 'Add to Build Path'

That should do it. You might have to 'clean' you project (Project->Clean...).

Answer (score 2):

You need to add [MySql jdbc driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html) in your classpath